# Using Trigger.io and Firebase

Tags: trigger.io, firebase

I saw [the tutorial on trigger.io's website](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/06/19/easily-sync-data-between-your-mobile-and-web-apps-using-firebase-and-trigger-io/) so I know it is supposed to work with Firebase, and it works in the iOS simulator. But I cannot get Firebase to work under Trigger.io on an actual iOS device.

My callbacks never get called regardless of what I do.

Is trigger somehow killing the websockets? Is there something else I need to do to get this to work on a device? I have the request/permissions set to allow `http://*/*`, `https://*/*`, and `*` but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Scratch that, it's intermittent in the simulator.

Comment: If I enable debug output I get this every once in a while on the device but not the simulator: [DEBUG] purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1e5ac4e0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've based your code on my [Wine Box app example](https://github.com/amirnathoo/Wine-Box/tree/firebase) then your issues may have been caused by an out of date Firebase library.

I updated the repos yesterday with the latest library and new way of referencing your Firebase using firebaseio.com rather than gamma.firebase.com.

Before that update, using the old library caused errors like this in the JavaScript console when building / running for web (forge run web):

```
Unexpected response code: 200 :3000:1
WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. :3000:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

So... first thing to check would be that you're using the latest Firebase library.